# Scheduling R script to run with crontab on Mac

Tags: r, cron

time crontab user.

I am on a MacOS Mojave Version 10.14.3.

I saved a cronjob with this command:

`25 21 * * * Rscript /Users/jasonbaik/Documents/pbp-animation/update-data.R`

However, nothing happens, and I see a mail:

[image]

Apparently, the command `Rscript` was not found...

However, when I just run `Rscript /Users/jasonbaik/Documents/pbp-animation/update-data.R` in my terminal, everything seems to be working...

Comment: Can you just use the full path to Rscript in the Cron file?

Comment: How do I find the full path to Rscript?

Comment: I would think `which Rscript` in a terminal would tell you.